# Microsoft Graph API C# Get all list items with PersonOrGroup column expanded

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

i am trying to get all list items using the Microsoft Graph API in C#.
Since the documentation is sparsely populated i am currently having troubles to get all list items containing all the columns with the PersonOrGroup columns contains the name of the person.

```
ListItem result = 
graphClient.Sites[SiteId].Lists[ListId].Items[ItemId]
  .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
      requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] 
        { "fields($select=tisPerson)" };
    }
   ).Result;
```

This is my code and it seems to only select the specified columns but ignores all other columns.
I also tried to add other columns like a text column into the select statement, but nothing happens.
The select statement seems to only react to PersonOrGroup columns.

Is there any way to get all list items from a list with the items containing all the columns and the PersonOrGroup columns to contain the name of the person?

Answer (score -3):

You can refer to following code to get all items

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Load the app settings from the appsettings.json file
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

var graphOptions = configuration.GetSection("GraphOptions").Get<GraphOptions>();

// Create an instance of the GraphServiceClient with authentication
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {
    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(graphOptions.ClientId)
        .WithAuthority(graphOptions.Authority)
        .WithClientSecret(graphOptions.ClientSecret)
        .Build();

    var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(graphOptions.Scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();

    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I seem to not be able to understand your code. How does your code load any list items, let alone expanding any PersonOrGroup column. If I can give you any clarification please tell me. Could you also please elaborate your code example?

Comment: Many of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.  If you didn't use AI here, keep in mind that code-only answers often aren't helpful, as @2Who mentioned.  Please make sure to provide an explanation of why you feel this will answer the question.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.